# Target class [App\http\Controllers\FrontController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

My whole code running perfectly in localhost but its showing this error `Target class [App\http\Controllers\FrontController] does not exist.` in server and the other page which is not connected with controller working fine.

Comment: in which file do you get this error and can you provide that file?

Comment: The namespaces are case sensitive

Comment: namespace are correct everywhere in same way. I am getting this error only those pages where i am using controller like admin controller and all but all code running in localhost even server configuration are same like php version and all

Comment: every where the namespace is written App\http\Controllers

Comment: Please share more details, and please do not use irrelevant tags - I don't think that this is related to Ubuntu in any way

Comment: Thanks for helping me i got the solution now many thanks to Muddassir Izhar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[App\http\Controllers\FrontController]
```

change **http** to **Http**

Comment: your welcome. kindly mark it accept if this answer helps you. thanks